# Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

When i make property as id!:string; or id:string=''; when i assign the value of params i get an error

(property) MoreParametersComponent.id: string
ts(2322)Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-more-parameters',
  templateUrl: './more-parameters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./more-parameters.component.css']
})
export class MoreParametersComponent implements OnInit {
  id!: string; // or id:string='';
  id2:number=0;
  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
      this.id=params.get('id'); // gives the above error here
      this.id2=parseInt(params.get('id2'));//error
    });
  }

}
```

How do I get around this error?

My Rest of the Code:

app.component.html

```
<a routerLink=""> Home </a><br>
<a routerLink="one-parameter,'p01'"> One-Parameter </a><br>
<a routerLink="more-parameter,{id:'p02',id2:123}"> More-Parameter </a> 
<br><br>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<br><br>
```

Route.config.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MoreParametersComponent } from './more-parameters/more-parameters.component';
import { OneParamterComponent } from './one-paramter/one-paramter.component';


export const mainroute:Routes=[
    {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
    {path:'one-parameter',component:OneParamterComponent},
    {path:'more-parameter',component:MoreParametersComponent}
];
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? It looks like `params.get` may return `null`, and `null` is not assignable to `this.id`. You need to handle this case.

Comment: Now i perform some changes on my  code by adding some necessary code about this problem.

Comment: you can always use `this.id=params.get('id') || null` or `this.id2=parseInt(params.get('id') || 0)`

Comment: Just set `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` and assign the value. I think dealing with this is just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: `id: string | null;`

Comment: yaahh!!  id:string|null or id!=string  is also not work for me but use  id:any; assign the error is gone. actually the problem i face due to <a [routerLink]="['/path',parameter1,parameter2]"> component </a> not given proper syntax

Answer (score 3):

The return of [ParamMap.get](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) is `string | null` which does not match your `id` type.

You could cast the return of ParamMap.get to a string like `params.get('id') as string`

Or you could subscribe on `params` instead which returns an object with property type any and access the the id param as an object key `params.id`. See https://angular.io/api/router/Params

Comment: thanks!! Mehyar for Responding.

Comment: "Casting" it via `as string` will only tell the compiler to *treat* the value as string. In fact, it still may very well be a `null` value and cause errors along the way. A better solution would be to add an additional check whether the value is null or not and only use the return value if it's a valid useable value.

Comment: Which kind of errors will be caused along the way? When a null is passed as a param, this means that the problem happened before when the route passes a wrong value for the ID param. This should be prevented before receiving the ID value from the param. But of course it is not a bad idea to check on the ID value in the activated Route, but it's also not definitely needed